# CSS selector containing any number?

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS selectors to target all classes starting with col-1, col-2, col-3, col-, ... [class*="col-"]. But I'm having a conflict with some other third party integration classes: `col-md-11`, `col-lg-2`, `col-sm-3`.

Does anyone have any ideas to just pick out classes: col-1, col-2, col-3, col-, ... in the most concise way (maybe just one line of code)?

```html
<div class="row row_1">
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-10"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-11"></div>
</div>
<div class="row row_2">
  <div class="col-12"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-8"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little convoluted but you could combine what you have with the [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector;

```css
[class*='col-']:not([class*='col-md'],[class*='col-lg'],[class*='col-sm']){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row_1">
  <div class="col-4">Red</div>
  <div class="col-10">Red</div>
  <div class="col-3">Red</div>
  <div class="col-md-11">Not Red</div>
</div>
<div class="row row_2">
  <div class="col-12">Red</div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">Not Red</div>
  <div class="col-8">Red</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">Not Red</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe using a caret instead of asterix would improve this for the question is about classes "starting with".

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber the problem with using the caret is that if it wasn't your first class it wouldn't work

Comment: You could test for both - `:is([class^='col-'], [class*=' col-']):not(...)` which would avoid matching e.g. `x-col-1`